# Match Threshold Filtering in OpenCV (Matlab conversion)

Tags: matlab, opencv

The current task is to attempt a 1 to 1 replication of Matlab image stabilization code  with openCV for a real time application (analyze stabilized frames, no video output).  I'm currently prototyping in Python but the end goal is C++ and CUDA functions.  Yes, I know there are better ways. Right now the powers that be think my transformation matrices should produce results within 0.1 pixels.

The issue seems to be replicating Matlab's [matchFeatures](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/matchfeatures.html) function running with default arguments (sum of squares, exhaustive, ratio 0.6, threshold 1%, SURF features).  It seems to have both a 0.6 ratio test (easily replicated with knnMatch, k=2 and a simple for loop) and a 1% of ideal match threshold filter.  I actually fired up the C coder which gave me some hints along with the actual documentation.  A normalized match distance can range from 0 (ideal) to 4.  The threshold filter is thus set at 0.04.  Of course the C coder output is so obfuscated it might as well be assembly language.

Just filtering match results (DMatch::distance) to keep less than 0.04 isn't the answer.  I can tell from the C code that some sort of normalization is going on to produce the matchMetrics in Matlab, but I don't understand the underlying math.  Can anyone shed some light on the match distance normalization process?

Comment: The normalized match distance you speak of is that returned by OpenCV or matlab? What happens when you set the 0,04 filter, registered results are too different from the matlab results?  Also maybe list the C code you ran into , its not at the link you have afaict.

Comment: The normalized match distance is returned by Matlab.  I guess what I'm asking is what math is Matlab doing to generate the match  metric.